# case dentro de select mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

Siguiendo con la migración de SYBASE a MySQL he encontrado el siguiente caso, un case dentro de la select. Dejo el ejemplo por si podríais orientarme como hacerlo. Muchas gracias!!

```
select mvfg_cantidad * case mvfg_tipo_origen when 'P' then 1 else -1 end  w_mov   
          from mvfg_mvto_fungibles
         where mvfg_marca = p_marca and mvfg_modelo = p_modelo and mvfg_fecha >= p_fecha and
               ( ( mvfg_tipo_origen = 'P' and mvfg_origen = p_destino) or
                 ( mvfg_tipo_destino = 'P' and mvfg_destino = p_destino)) 
         order by mvfg_fecha desc;
```

Comment: Nos podrías indicar "tu pregunta"?

Comment: La estructura de control [`CASE` (ver página del manual de la versión 5.5, por ejemplo)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) está soportada por MySQL. ¿Qué problema tienes? A primera vista parece que te falta el separador de campos en el `SELECT`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, resulta que estamos migrando de SYBASE a MySQL y hay cosas como esta en las que me pierdo y no encuentro como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

El sustituto de CASE en MySQL es la sintaxis de IF:

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Tendrías que poner la sentencia IF entre paréntesis.

[CASE documentación](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/CACHAIGD.htm)

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me pongo a ello